# How does IntelliJ decide if a class is a test class or?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I'm using IntelliJ with a groovy code base.

It's always very flaky, but one thing I see regularly is sometimes it refuses to put a green arrow next to *some* of my tests:

[image]

It adds green arrows for tests in some test classes but not others and I can't see why because many of them are pretty much the same.

Sometimes a rebuild fixes it sometimes not. Usually I have to git clean and totally reinitialize the project.

What is frustrating is tests *do* work. I can right click right on `@Test` and choose `Run <my test>` and it works fine, but I don't have the green arrow in the gutter.

But the big issue is I am not able to run an entire test class. If I right click on the `class myclass...` line it gives me no option to run it. If I right click the file itself it also gives me no option. For the classes it adds arrows to I can do this and execute all tests in a class.

I guess I'd like to know a little more about how the IDE decided to mark a class as a test class or not:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share any project sample demonstrating the issue?

Comment: I'll need to create a new project from scratch to try to reproduce. The current project is huge. What components need to be included in the question?

Comment: at least show the diff between classes that working/not working, show annotations, show imports, which junit you are using...